# fts-alfresco search giving wrong results on s*

Tags: solr, full-text-search, alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I am searching in Alfresco node browser with @xyz:attribute:`*pks*`(no node is present with value pks) and in the result am getting nodes containing "pkk". Below is few test cases and results.

```
    search keyword    results

    *pks*  ----------node containing "pkk"

    *pkq* ---------- no results found

    *pkk*  ----------node containing "pkk"

cm:name:*xls* ----- node containing xls, xle, xlu
```

Alfresco version : 5.0.3.5

It would be so helpful if someone could help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those the actual terms you're searching for? What does the analysis page for Solr show for the field type and the values indexed / queried?

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thanks for the quick reply. attribute and the model is different but the terms are same. I don't know how to check in the analysis page. Can you please help with that?

Comment: It's available under the Solr admin page and the collection name.

Comment: could you show your schema.xml for your field?

Comment: @MatsLindh: am new to solr, so am still trying to figure out how to get the field name. Am using Alfresco tool which internally uses solr for indexing and we didn't make any changes to solr.

Comment: @Mysterion: thanks for the reply, am not sure how schema is generated for custom fields by Alfresco. :(

Comment: @MatsLindh: I was doing some works on the analysis page of Solr, I kept the field type as text_en, field value(index) as "GYM FORM.xle" and field value(Query) as "xls*". In analysis result report at the end for "porter stem filter" text is "form.xl" (left side) and "xl" (right side). When i changed the field value (query) to "xlp*", for "porter stem filter" text is "form.xl" (left side) and "xlp" (right side). "p" is not geting removed but s is getting removed for "porter stem filter". can this be the reason?

Comment: That would probably be the reason, yes. The stemming is removing `s` at the end of the word, since this usually indicates plurality in English (i.e. football**s**). Use a field type without stemming.